# vaadin access session attribute that was put in filter

Tags: httprequest, vaadin, httpsession

I've got multiple filters.
In one of the filters I've got this code

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String url = request.getRequestURI();

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (request.getParameter("xxxx") != null)
    session.setAttribute("xxxx", request.getParameter("xxxx"));
chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

For UI I use `VAADIN` 7. 
And I decided to display the value of the parameter `xxxx` in the table. 
So I wanted to do it like this

```
Table table = new Table("Data.");
table.setSizeFull();
table.addContainerProperty("Field", String.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Value", String.class, null);
table.setStyleName("wordwrap-table");
table.setStyleName("user-table");

Object attribute = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("xxxx");
```

However `attribute` value is `null`.
Why? And how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another `getSession()` in there:

```
Object attribute = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("xxxx");
```

The result of `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` is the current *Vaadin Session*. The next `getSession()` gets you the *HTTP session*, which is where your attributes live.